# What is best practice for updating Laravel site cached data?

Tags: php, performance, caching

I want to updating a Laravel site **cached** data based on custom logic;
my Laravel app is caching some data for period of time, but this is not so good for me, because  I want to that cached data be updated smartly based on performant and custom logic, so that's why I am looking for methods of doing this job;
as more details: my web site page's data continuously are changing because this is user centered site, so that continuously are receiving data and interact from users side , also that has recommending logic in presenting data to users.

I need big picture about this subject.

Comment: when I faced performance problem for first time, I did not know clear understanding of this kinds of problem's solution, so I want to have big picture of this problem solutions and their prerequisites and consequences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better if you give more information about your workflow.

Using the commands metionend before can be useful but **you detele all the cache**, and translated in performance is like to don't have a cache.

(But this depens on your application)

For a big or scalable application, **You need to think with an event driven philosophy**, example:

In your crud you can add multiple type of object (cars, animals, persons)

In the home page you want the cached result for each on of this:

- You need to create a query for the cars, one for the animal, one for the person

If you add one car, and you perform a `Cache::flush();` when you go back to the home you will have 3 query, one for the car, one for the animals, one for the persons.

If you create a CarChangeListner and a CarUpdateCacheEvent, you can rebuild under the hood only the cars cache.

Result: when you go back to the home you will have the result with no query(1)

Delieting all the cache, is the most easiest way to get the result, but if your application grow up with a big amount of data, the performance will be impacted.

The event driven way is much difficult to implement, but performance and scalabilty will be greater.

(1) everything depends in how many time the cache will be upgraded.

[Laravel Event Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/events#generating-events-and-listeners)

[Laravel Cache Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/cache#obtaining-a-cache-instance)

Comment: Yes,  you're right, thanks for your explanations.

Comment: I'll try to add some detail to this question and problem in future

Answer (score 0):

You can call php artisan command like this after CRUD operations:

**script**

```
Artisan::call('cache:clear');
```

Or you can use Cache facade:

```
Cache::flush();
```

For more information [Laravel Cache](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/cache#removing-items-from-the-cache)

Comment: In this way you delete all the laravel cache, so is like not have a cache.
As you know depens in how many objects you store in the cache, but creating or ugrading the cache of the single object olso if is much difficult is more performance frienldy.

Answer (score -2):

With the following command, it should work:

```
Cache::flush();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).